# Maximum upvote and downvote a question or answer can receive

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, down-votes, up-votes

Is there a limitation in the upvote or downvote for a particular question or answer can receive?

Comment: Number of users with enough reputation to up- resp. downvote (minus one for the author of the post, possibly, since one can't vote on one's own posts).

Comment: Voting limit should be, for example 50.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [database schema in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), it appears that post score is saved as an integer, which in [MS SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) can go up to **2,147,483,647**.

So, theoretically, the maximum *score* is about 2 billion. However, the maximum number of votes could be infinite, since you could have downvotes offsetting the upvotes.

With a rep gain of 10 points per upvote though, you're going to be limited by the user's reputation (also an int), so a single user could only get 2 million upvotes total, unless you account for the rep cap, which throws everything off.

In reality, the internal structure is probably somewhat different from what's shown in the public database, and I doubt we'll be seeing anyone with 2 million rep anytime soon. The highest voted *question* on SO is only around [4500 points right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array), so I think we're probably safe.

Comment: After which, it rolls over to negative two billion, and you're permanently banned from SO.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the software would do if a post got that many upvotes. Maybe we can convince a bored dev to try it on the dev site sometime and tell us what happens. I wonder if there's some internal logic to cap it at a certain point, or if it would just break everything.

Comment: Jon Skeet is in trouble...

Answer (score 7):

You may count limit as following ,

```
Maximum Upvotes limit = total number of users 
                        - users less than 15 reputation 
                        + an unknown no of deleted users who's votes were kept after deletion 
                        + the zombie votes from migrated questions

Maximum Downvotes limit = total number of users 
                         - users less than 125 reputation
                         + an unknown no of deleted users who's votes were kept after deletion 
                         + the zombie votes from migrated questions
```

Comment: + an unknown number of deleted users who's votes were kept after deletion. + the zombie votes from migrated questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no limitation for a post to receive votes.

Comment: Although theoretically at some point the number may overflow...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - True. But that is not the limitation of voting.