# Is there a maximum number of answers to one question?

Tags: support, answers

The [Proposed Question Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1847/16402) on [meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com), formed by a merge of 14 questions, currently has 510 answers (don't worry, it's all under control!). I'm worried that if there is a maximum, it might be reached.

I was previously concerned that the number of answers may be stored as an 8-bit integer, and hence the limit would be 256, but this is obviously not the case.

**Is there a maximum number of answers to a single question?** If not, is this because the databases use an integer type of arbitrary size? If yes, what causes it (the use of 32-bit integers, say)?

Comment: Almost same thing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178418/maximum-upvote-and-downvote-a-question-or-answer-can-receive

Comment: It's actually extremely difficult to limit the number of items in a set in a relational database. Unless there's a clear need (number of seats in a venue for instance) there's rarely a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no limit other than the limits on the *total number of posts in site*.

An answer is a type of post, but one with a parent question foreign key. When displaying a question, all answers are retrieved with a SQL join.

Post ids use the [`int` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx), limiting sites to 2,147,483,647 (2 billion plus change) posts.